# Why is packets by received from socket less than captured by Wireshark?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, wireshark

I got a very strange problem.

My code only received `87266` packets, but there are `167917` packets in Wireshark

This is my code(python3):

```
counter = 0
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(10)
sock.bind(('', 57130))
while True:
    try:
        data, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        counter += 1
    except socket.timeout:
        break
print(counter)
exit(0)
```

It output `87266`

But in Wireshark i got `167917` packets

[image]

I marked all of packets that `dstport == 57130` and export them to a file, then open this file, so these `No.` are successive.

My OS is `Windows 7`

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer, but what happens if you increase 4096 to something bigger?  8192, 16384, ...?  Perhaps Python can't process packets fast enough and your buffer is too small for the packet flow rate?  Looking quickly at the timestamps, there seem to be a lot of packets all arriving within a very short time of each other.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a network filter driver that intercepts specific frames so that Wireshark can't see them. They're counted by the NIC driver but not in Wireshark.